# The link is being rendered but not redirecting using <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have been trying to redirect the page using `<Link>` and what i have is that the URL changes but the page does not redirect. Only after i refresh the page, it show.
I have searched and found some links:
1. One on the [correct syntax](https://forums.meteor.com/t/link-changes-url-but-does-not-rerender-the-component/44027)
2. i have implemented the link in small [HTML](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4975)

Now here is the part of my Code

**App.Js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Switch , Route , BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './section/home';
import Oneup from './section/oneup';
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main homepage">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/oneup" component={Oneup} exact={true} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**main_content.js**

Here i have included `<Link>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
class Main_content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ib-center">
         <BrowserRouter>
            <Link to="/oneup" class="btn">VIEW CASE</Link>
         </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now i can't figure out where i am going wrong.
the link generated is fine and working when refreshed manually.

Comment: No need to use `BrowserRouter` in main_content

Comment: That's it !! Its solved the problem !! You are a life saviour. I should have asked earlier, it would have saved me hours. But if am using footer menu the page is redirected to the bottom of the redirected page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one BrowerRouter to wrap, you have used BrowerRouter in App.js and main_content.js too

```
class Main_content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ib-center">
         <div>
            <Link to="/oneup" class="btn">VIEW CASE</Link>
         </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```